# How to make link button on grid view invisible when I click on it?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a grid view with link buttons. When clicking on it, I want to perform some operation, and also need to make the clicked link button invisible. How to make it invisible?

My code:

```
 <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="true" HeaderText="Theory">
      <ItemTemplate>
           <asp:LinkButton ID="lb_theory" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("student_id")%>' OnClientClick="this.disabled = true; "   CommandName="theory_remove" Text="Remove"  
command = "lnk_Click" ></asp:LinkButton>
      </ItemTemplate>
      </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="true" HeaderText="Practical">
                 <ItemTemplate>
                      <asp:LinkButton ID="lb_practical" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" 
                                CommandArgument='<%#Eval("student_id")%>'   CommandName="practical_remove" Text="Remove"></asp:LinkButton>
                 </ItemTemplate>
      </asp:TemplateField>
```

and

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
     if (e.CommandName == "theory_remove")
     {
         string st_id = Convert.ToString(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
         string t_id = (string)Session["test"];
         SqlConnection con = obj.getcon();
         con.Open();
         string theory_state = "0";
         SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("update student_vs_testsession_details set theory='" + theory_state+ "' WHERE student_id='" + st_id + "' and testsession_id='" + t_id + "'", con);
         int temp = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
     }
}
```

Comment: did you see my code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way

```
protected void gridview__RowCommand(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{


        GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)(((LinkButton)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer);
        LinkButton lnkbtn = (LinkButton)row.FindControl(”lnkbtnActionNames”);
        lnkbtn .Visible = false;


}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would personally use [Knockout JS](http://knockoutjs.com/) or [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) to manage all my client side functionality just as hiding and manipulating html elements.

Comment: what will be the jquery for this? @Cubicle.Jockey

Comment: Why not mootools, signalr, greasemonkey  and angular as well?

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your GridView1_RowCommand event

```
    LinkButton mybutton = (LinkButton)sender;
    mybutton.Visible = false;
```

Comment: it shows an error "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView' to type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton'." please help @TheProvost

Answer (score 0):

use javascript to hide that. Add onclientclick event and write code in javascript to hide that. First client code will run and then server side. So the button will be hide at that time.